# Как в массиве сделать перенос строки?

Tags: python, list

Вот как выводит `[[-1, 0, 1, 5], [2, 5, 22, 5], [-6, 2, 5, 3], [7, 2, 3, -5]]`

А мне нужно прийти к виду

```
[[-1, 0, 1, 5],
 [2, 5, 22, 5],
 [-6, 2, 5, 3],
 [7, 2, 3, -5]]
```

Вот сам код:

```
matrix = [[-1,0,1,5],
    [2,5,22,5],
    [-6,2,5,3],
    [7,2,3,-5]]

print(matrix)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Numpy` умеет красиво печатать двумерные массивы:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = [[-1, 0, 1, 5], [2, 5, 22, 5], [-6, 2, 5, 3], [7, 2, 3, -5]]
print(np.array(matrix))
```

Напечатается:

```
[[-1  0  1  5]
 [ 2  5 22  5]
 [-6  2  5  3]
 [ 7  2  3 -5]]
```

Или вот так, если хотите с запятыми:

```
print(np.array2string(np.array(matrix), separator=', '))
```

```
[[-1,  0,  1,  5],
 [ 2,  5, 22,  5],
 [-6,  2,  5,  3],
 [ 7,  2,  3, -5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант через [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint):

```
from pprint import pprint

matrix = [[-1, 0, 1, 5], [2, 5, 22, 5], [-6, 2, 5, 3], [7, 2, 3, -5]]

pprint(matrix, width=20)
```

Результат:

```
[[-1, 0, 1, 5],
 [2, 5, 22, 5],
 [-6, 2, 5, 3],
 [7, 2, 3, -5]]
```

Параметр `width` отвечает за максимальную длину выводимой на экран строки. По умолчанию он равен 80, и исходный вид списка (в одну строку) в эту длину укладывается (в нем 60 символов), и чтобы `pprint` выводил каждую строку матрицы на отдельной строке, нужно эту длину уменьшить.

Подойдет любое значение меньше длины списка в строковом виде, можно прямо так и вычислять:

```
pprint(matrix, width=len(str(matrix))-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```py
print("[" + ",\n".join("[" + ", ".join(map(str,i)) + "]" for i in matrix) + "]")
```

или просто

```py
print("[", end="")
print(*matrix, sep=",\n", end="]\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in matrix:
     print(row)
```

Вот таким способом можно выводить матрицу в её нормальном виде!

Comment: На выводе будет несколько списков, а не матрица.